Deleting records from my mongodb database using flask
I want to delete records from my MongoDB. When I click on the delete button nothing happens.
this is my html part:
  <!-- Manager Delete Modal -->

      {% for manager in managers %}
        <div class="manager">
            <!-- Deleting a manager -->`your text`
            <div id="deleteEmployeeModal" class="modal fade">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('views.delete_manager', id=manager['_id']) }}">
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Cancel">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}

,this is the my route:

@views.route('/\<string:id\>/delete_manager/', methods=\['POST'\])
def delete_manager(id):
if request.method == 'POST':
managers.delete_one({"\_id": ObjectId(id)})
return redirect(url_for('views.adminHome'))

and this is my MongoDB database:
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.RentCars_db # creating your flask database using your mongo client


The first step is to verify if the delete_manager route is even being called.  Add a print() statement to that function, so you can see if it appears in the server log output.

Please provide an error handler to your code if not done. It would help to catch and report the error thrown by the database. For instance, while trying to delete from database, if any error occurs, an error handler should catch and report it.  The actual reason for the failure will be demystified from the error thrown from database.

Add logs/print statements on the delete_manager to ensure it's getting called and with the correct id. Also, why do you have a \  before the <> brackets in the route? More importantly, the backslash before the _ in managers.delete_one({"\_id": ObjectId(id)}) changes nothing in the string. It will do a comparison against a field named  \_id instead of _id. So unless your id field is actually \_id in the database, it will never match any object to delete.
